# CakePHP database relations: songs with singers and writers

Tags: php, cakephp, database-design, cakephp-model

A song can have multiple singers and multiple writers. There's overlap, so some singers write and some writers sing - i.e. there's no need for two seperate tables. How should I have the relations so that there's a single "artists" table, so when I'm adding a song, have one/some of those artists be set as the singers and one/some of them be set as the writers?

By the way (unrelated), I'm using an application called "Petit four" to create the database structure and bake the application: http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en

Answer (score 1):

You can use aliases in your Song model - something like this:

```
$this->Song->hasAndBelongsToMany(
                 'Writer'=>array(
                    'className'=>'Artist',
                    'joinTable'=>'writers_songs'
                  )
);

$this->Song->hasAndBelongsToMany(
                 'Singer'=>array(
                    'className'=>'Artist',
                    'joinTable'=>'singers_songs'
                  )
);
```

And of course you will need your association tables `writers_songs` and `artists_songs`.

Check out [the manual for HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-hab):